Put sql column values as parameter in API to download data in sql
I have company_id values in sql table all_company_details. I want to use these values to call the api which looks like www.api.company.com?companyid=1221
The data needs to be downloaded for all companies using this procedure.
I tried to make flow like this that I get data from lookup activity.
then i use set variable from the output, and use that variable in api expression so for each company id, data is downloaded.
API link was working fine before but now company_id argument is added as data has increased and data can be loaded incrementally.

I made Lookup activity which gives me column like this

Lookup activity output looks like this

I then used ForEach activity and used
@activity('Lookup_company_id').output.value

Then I used set variable

I am not sure how to colve all of it as it is giving errors. First time on here, apologies if this is not clear


The issue is in the expression that you are giving in the set variable activity.
When you give the expression as @item() in the set variable activity, the value will look like {comp_id:1221} for each iteration in the foreach loop activity.
Instead of passing only the value of comp_id, both the key_column_name and value are getting passed as Json. This is the reason for the error in your pipeline
To solve this, give the value for set variable activity as @item().comp_id. This will make sure you are passing only the value.


